# Spotify access token only works once for added users

Tags: android, access-token, spotify

I have an Android app that uses Spotify API to get the top tracks of the users. App works fine with my account which is also used to create the app on Spotify dashboard. I have added another user to the dashboard. When I get that user's access token, I can only use that token once to request the data(I get the result successfully). But when I try for the second time to do the same request, I get this error: *User not registered in the Developer Dashboard* . **It is registered**.

I tried to create another app on Spotify dashboard, but still the issue persists. Can anyone help?